# How to send a list of numbers / strings with scrapyd to a spider when using scrapyd.schedule

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to start my scrapy bot from a Django application and I need to pass in a list of strings and also a list of numbers that the bot requires to function. This is my code in the views.py of my Django application:

```
task = scrapyd.schedule('default', 'arc', 
            settings=settings, numIds=numIds, formOp=formOp)
```

numId is the list of the numbers I need to pass and fromOp is the list of strings I need to pass. I tried extracting them in the scrapy spider file using:

```
kwargs.get('numIds')
kwargs.get('formOp')
```

for some reason, it only gives me the first number/string in the list even if I try and send a JSON object. is there a way to pass the entire list through scrapyd?

Comment: `scrapyd.schedule('default', 'arc', settings=settings, numIds=json.dumps(numIds), formOp=json.dumps(formOp))` does not work?

Comment: @UmairAyub This worked, Thank you very much!!! how do I make it so it shows up as the Answer?